# Why `for` can iterate pairs, but `lambda i,x:` cannot `map` pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, iterable, enumerate

I could not find such a question in the archive.

With `for` is possible to *unpack* iterated pairs:

```
>>> for i, x in enumerate([5,10,15]): print('x[%d]=%d' % (i, x))
x[0]=5
x[1]=10
x[2]=15
```

or also is possible to **not** *unpack* them:

```
>>> for x in enumerate([5,10,15]): print(x)
(0, 5)
(1, 10)
(2, 15)
```

However, when using `map()`, this *unpack* is not possible:

```
>>> list(map(lambda i, x: x**i, enumerate([5,10,15])))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Why is this? Design choice? And why?

I guess one could implement such a wrapper:

```
def map1(func, *iterables):
    from inspect import signature
    params = signature(func).parameters
    if len(params) == 1:
        yield from map(func, *iterables)
    else:
        yield from map(lambda x: func(*x), *iterables)
```

(works in every case)

or this other one, that blindly unpacks arguments:

```
def map2(func, *iterables):
    yield from map(lambda x: func(*x), *iterables)
```

(I guess the latter is going to cause some trouble)

Is there a (good) reason to not do it?

Comment: You're looking for [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

Comment: For the case of `enumerate`, you can use `list(map(lambda i, x: x**i, itertools.count(), [5,10,15]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue with `lambda` but with `map`.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) says:

> If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel.

In other words, the function must take the same number of arguments as the number of iterables that you pass.  The size of each individual element in the iterables is not relevant.

If you want to pass each *element* of a *single* iterable as multiple arguments, you can use `zip` and argument unpacking to transpose the sequence:

```
>>> map(lambda i, x: x**i, *zip(*enumerate([5,10,15])))
[1, 10, 225]
```

As Ashwini noted, you can also use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead of `map`.

Comment: Nice trick for transposing a sequence of sequence (+1). But I guess for the special case of enumerate one could just do `map(f, range(len(lst)), lst)`, no?

Comment: @mescalinum: Yes, you could do that for this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `enumerate()` returns a single enumerate object which holds pair of values in multiple enumerate objects. If you try:

```
>>> enumerate([5,10,15])
>>> <enumerate at 0x39152d8>
>>>e = enumerate([5,10,15])

>>> for i in e:
    print e

<enumerate object at 0x03915080>
<enumerate object at 0x03915080>
<enumerate object at 0x03915080>
```

What you are doing int his statement:

```
map(lambda i, x: x**i, enumerate([5,10,15]))
```

is passing `return` value of `enumerate()` to  `lambda`. So it gets only one value while you specified two arguments.
If you try:

```
>>>map(lambda i: i[0] * i[1], enumerate([5,10,15]))
>>> [0,10,30]
```

you get expected output